# Does MarkLogic TDE framework support including reusable template fragments?

Tags: marklogic

I have several SQL views that, in part, share some data elements. I'd like to create a fragment template (TDE) that encapsulates the shared data so it can be reused by multiple parent templates.

Does MarkLogic TDE framework support this?

Answer (score 1):

While TDEs don't have a special mechanism for reuse of common fragments, TDEs are specified as JSON or XML documents.

As a result, standard JSON or XML transformation tools can generate the TDE loaded into the schemas database from JSON or XML fragments in the project directory.

For instance, XSLT would be a typical tool for this kind of task when defining the TDE in XML.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks very much for answering. I'm using MarkLogic Data Hub and gradle for development. Would I be able to accomplish this within that framework?

Comment: Also, I'm currently using JSON for the TDEs (but can switch to XML/XSLT). Would I just use some query console scripts to generate the TDEs and then add the query console output to Data Hub config?

Comment: Custom Gradle tasks can execute Java code, it would certainly be possible to write a Gradle task that merges fragments of JSON documents.  Such a Gradle task wouldn't have to know anything specific to TDE. Gradle might even have an existing plugin that could be used for this purpose - check:  https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=JSON It's certainly possible to use JavaScript in Query Console to merge JSON files, but a Gradle task would presumably be easier to automate.